# Can't create old "Text" node in NUKE 11.3v4

Tags: python, nuke

I'm using NUKE 11.3v4 on macOS Mojave. Here's one problem: I can't use new class2 node `Text2`. Every time I choose it – my app expectedly quits. I'm having such a behaviour only on macOS. On Windows and Linux it runs fine. So I've written a little script to get rid of this issue (I wanna use old `Text` node instead of new `Text2` node). But my script doesn't work. Why?

Code in `menu.py` file:

```
import os
import sys
import nuke

toolbar = nuke.menu('Nodes')

if os.name == 'posix' and sys.platform == 'darwin':
    toolbar.addCommand('Draw/Text', 'nuke.createNode("Text")', 'crtl+alt+shift+t', icon='Text.png')
    nuke.message("Oops! Only Text1 node is accessible.")
else:
    toolbar.addCommand('Draw/Text', 'nuke.createNode("Text2")', 'crtl+alt+shift+t', icon='Text.png')
    nuke.message("Fine! Text2 node's ready for use.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. **It just was a `typo` in my code**:

```
'crtl+alt+shift+t'
```

instead of:

```
'ctrl+alt+shift+t'
```

It's a shortcut for calling a `Text` node:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

> Now my script works fine!!

```
import os
import sys
import nuke

toolbar = nuke.menu('Nodes')

if os.name == 'posix' and sys.platform == 'darwin':
    toolbar.addCommand('Draw/Text', 'nuke.createNode("Text")', 'ctrl+alt+shift+t', icon='Text.png')
    nuke.message("Oops! Only Text1 node is accessible.")
else:
    toolbar.addCommand('Draw/Text', 'nuke.createNode("Text2")', 'ctrl+alt+shift+t', icon='Text.png')
    nuke.message("Fine! Text2 node's ready for use.")
```

Hope this helps.